# Save the Column of CSV File in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, csv, while-loop

How to extract Column from CSV files in PHP.

#My data is like this, how to extract the country column and save it in array.

```
 a,b,c
 Andrew,US,23
 Bob,UK,21
 Stefani,UK,23
 Alen,UK,24
```

#CODE

```
$file = fopen("data.csv", "r");

while (($row = fgetcsv($file, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
   print_r($row);   
 }
```

#Output:

```
  Array
  (
   [0] => a
   [1] => b
   [2] => c
  )
  Array
  (
   [0] => Andrew
   [1] => US
   [2] => 23
  )
  Array
  (
   [0] => Bob
   [1] => UK
   [2] => 21
  )
  Array 
  (
   [0] => Stefani
   [1] => UK
   [2] => 23
  )
  Array
  (
   [0] => Alen
   [1] => UK
   [2] => 24
  )
```

I have got the Data in array Format now how do i extract Country column.

Comment: Each row is an array. To access the 2nd element you can address it directly. `echo $row[1];` Remember, arrays count from 0.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$arr = [];
while (($row = fgetcsv($file, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
   array_push($arr,$row[1]);
 }

$arr = array_unique($arr);
```

If that's what you want to do. This should contain all countries (without duplicates).

Comment: Using `$arr[] = $row[1];` should be preferred as `array_push($arr, $row[1])`.

Comment: Thanks for your time,appreciate it.